# Загрузка fragment, содержащий карту, по клику

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `layout` с 3-мя `fragment`, каждый из которых содержит карту. На каждом `fragment` - своя карта.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы карта загружалась только по клику на кнопке "Загрузить карту", например?

Дело в том, что этот `layout` не грузится на телефонах со слабой памятью, вызывая краш приложения. Вот и ищу обходной путь.

Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Cлабая память это сколько?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Просто сделайте вместо фрагмента с картой FrameLayout, и добавляйте туда карту в любой удобный для вас момент. Как добавить фрагмент в другом фрагменте - это уже легко гуглится

Comment: то есть мне нужно гуглить нечто вроде "fragment in fragment"? По правде говоря, слабо представляю, что именно должен искать.

Comment: да, гуглить примерно так. 
Но там на самом деле все просто, добавляется как в активити, только надо использовать ```getChildFragmentManager() вместо getFragmentManager()```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо фрагментов показывайте кнопки, при нажатии с помошью `FragmentManager` вставляйте фрагменты.

Но все-таки стоит подумать над дизайном, три карты на одном экране -- это перебор.